# How to return data using d3 inside a module.exports function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to read a json file using `d3.json` module inside a `module.exports` function.

I want to return data after call the module.exports file.

I tried:

```
const d3 = require('d3')
module.exports = () => {
  let jsonfile = 'link/to/json/file.json'
  d3.json(jsonfile, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    return data
  }
}
```

After call this module file, I get an `undefined` error. So I add a few changes to this code.

**First I defined a variable outside `d3.json` function**

```
const d3 = require('d3')
module.exports = () => {
  let out;
  let jsonfile = 'link/to/json/file.json'
  d3.json(jsonfile, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    out = data
  }
  return out
}
```

The output was also `undefined`.

**Second, I tried to use de inner function `d3.json` after calling module.exports file**

*`File A`*

```
const d3 = require('d3')
module.exports = () => {
  let jsonfile = 'link/to/json/file.json'
  this.out = d3.json(jsonfile, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    out = data
  }
  return out
}
```

However, I got a TypeError using the last method.

How can I return data from `d3.json` after call a module.exports file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export a promise or a function that returns a promise:

```
const d3 = require('d3')
module.exports = (file) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  d3.json(file, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else {
      resolve(data)
    }
 })
```

in your other file

```
jsonPromise('link/to/json/file.json').then(data => {
  // data available here
})
```